# Google Maps API v3: Initial View is Fine but Gray Box with No Map if View is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On the initial load of the map loads perfectly fine, but if you change to a different view then go back to the view containing the map, the map comes out gray.  If you resize the view the map comes out correctly.

The environment is a bit....complicated but essentially we're using angularjs with the jade template engine and stylus as the css preprocessor to create a webapp.

In addition to the source code I've also attached the screenshots of the map objects.  In one the map object is fine, but in the second there seems to be a tosurl that points to the terms of service page for the google maps api which may mean that something isnt being loaded properly.

[valid map object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAFgC.png)

[invalid map object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk7YN.png)

To repeat, the map loads perfectly fine initially but if we change to a separate page and then go back to the page containing the map. The map comes out gray until you either refresh or resize the view.

The map is recreated completely whenever the page containing the map is loaded. I have also tried calling resize on the view but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any input/advice/insight would be much appreciated.  Here's the code (I've modified it slightly to make it easier to read):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' *; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob: *; style-src 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: *; media-src *; connect-src *;">
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
      <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
      <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
      <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com">
      <title></title>
      <!-- link(rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/startup.png") //for startup image on ios-->
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <!-- build:css css/index.css-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
      <!-- endbuild    -->
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAJ5Z1l30hcJxETpewJN7yiki0y4gnkd_s"></script>
      <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onLoad=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var google = window.google;
        function GoogleMap(setLocation) {
            // create default options
            var options = {
                center          : new google.maps.LatLng(35.6895000, 139.6917100),
                zoom            : 15,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                mapTypeId       : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var googleMap = this;
            var canvas = window.document.getElementById('googleMap');
            canvas.style.height = '415px';

            googleMap.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            googleMap.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            googleMap.markers = [];
            googleMap.watch = {'prevLat' : null, 'prevLng' : null};
            googleMap.map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, options);
            googleMap.directionsDisplay.setMap(googleMap.map);
            googleMap.getCurrentPosition(setLocation); // creates a marker at the users current position
        }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="googleMap" flex="flex"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you change the view, you need to trigger the map resize event.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Depends on how the viewed is changed, you and manual trigger this event in the view changed function or add to map bounds_change events

```
function viewedChanged (){
   dosomething();
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}


//or

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry, adding the event listener worked. The map comes back nicely though slightly off from the original location, but I can work that out.  Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad it helps. Remember to set the centre back after resizing